# Creating a DbContextFactory that gets the connection string from user-secrets

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Working on a DotNetCore solution with a `WebApi` project and a separate `Data` project that houses the Entity Framework implementation. We've been upgrading libraries as they come out, so we're using all of the newest Core stuff.

In the `Data` project, we created an `ApplicationDbContextFactory` in order to create migrations (needs a parameterless constructor). Due to the parameterless constructor constraint when adding a migration, you can't inject `IOptions<>` to easily access `appsettings.json` values. We ended up using a `ConfigurationBuilder` to pull in the `WebApi`'s `appsettings.json` file(s).

We recently changed the `ApplicationDbContextFactory` to also pull in `user-secrets`. This allows each developer to use a custom connection string without having to ignore a file or remember to not commit something.

Since making this change, using `dotnet ef migrations add MIGRATION_NAME` works just fine in command line. However, using `add-migration MIGRATION_NAME` in Visual Studio's Package Manager Console now appears to be broken with the following error:

> add-migration : Exception calling “Substring” with “1" argument(s):
>   “StartIndex cannot be less than zero.  Parameter name: startIndex”  At
>   line:1 char:1  + add-migration TESTING  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Migration], MethodInvocationException
>        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException,Add-Migration

I tried a few variations of the command to see if it needed the context to be specified (among other things), but nothing seemed to get around this error. It never seems to get past the constructor in `ApplicationDbContextFactory`.

Here's the code I'm referring to:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Models.Domain.Settings;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        private readonly SolutionSettings _settings;

        // In order to use 'add-migration' in Visual Studio, you have to have a parameterless constructor.
        // Otherwise you get "No parameterless constructor defined for this object." when creating a migration.
        public ApplicationDbContextFactory()
        {
        }

        public ApplicationDbContextFactory(IOptions<SolutionSettings> settings)
        {
            _settings = settings.Value;
        }

        public ApplicationDbContext Create(DbContextFactoryOptions options)
        {
            // If the IOptions signature was hit, we can just pull the dbconnection from settings
            if (_settings != null && _settings.DbConnection != null)
            {
                var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
                    .UseSqlServer(_settings.DbConnection, opts => {
                        opts.EnableRetryOnFailure();
                        opts.MigrationsAssembly("Data");
                    });

                return new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
            }
            else
            {
                // Otherwise, we have to get the settings manually...
                return Create(options.ContentRootPath, options.EnvironmentName);
            }
        }

        private ApplicationDbContext Create(string basePath, string environmentName)
        {
            // HACK: To pull from WebApi\appsettings.json
            basePath = basePath.Replace("Data", "WebApi");

            Console.Write($"PATH & ENV: {basePath}, {environmentName}" + Environment.NewLine);

            // Pull in the WebApi\appsettings.json files, apply user secrets
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(basePath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName.ToLower()}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                // This needs to match the UserSecretsId value in the WebApi.csproj
                // Also added a UserSecretsId key with the same value to Data.csproj to suppress a warning
                // Adding this was the only way it would actually override values with user-secret values
                .AddUserSecrets("USER_SECRETS_ID")
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            var config = builder.Build();
            var connectionString = config["SolutionSettings:DbConnection"];

            Console.Write($"CONNECTION STRING: {connectionString}" + Environment.NewLine);

            return Create(connectionString);
        }

        private ApplicationDbContext Create(string connectionString)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
                throw new ArgumentException(
                    $"{nameof(connectionString)} is null or empty.",
                    nameof(connectionString));

            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .UseSqlServer(connectionString, options => {
                    options.EnableRetryOnFailure();
                    options.MigrationsAssembly("Data");
                });

            return new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

As a side note; while troubleshooting this I added `opts.EnableRetryOnFailure();` and `opts.MigrationsAssembly("Data");`, but I don't know that they make any difference in this context.

My questions:

- This was initially implemented during the RC era of Core and may be a little outdated. Is there a better way to accomplish pulling user-secret values when creating migrations? Is it still a thing to use the factory like this?
- Anyone know why we're getting that error in Visual Studio's Package Manager Console?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since you posted it, but I've just had this error and found out the reason (even though it makes no sense)

The problem is in the line

```
console.Write($"CONNECTION STRING: {connectionString}" + Environment.NewLine);
```

If you romove the colon after CONNECTION STRING it works.
I have no idea why the colon in the interpolation is causing this error