# Error in migrations in EFCore

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

When I run Add-Migration using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 1.1.1, I get the following error:

> Add-Migration : Exception calling "Substring" with "1" argument(s):
>   "StartIndex cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: startIndex" At
>   line:1 char:1
>   + Add-Migration
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Migration], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException,Add-Migration

The same stuff works perfect with version 1.1.0-preview4-final

Comment: Similar unanswered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806813/creating-a-dbcontextfactory-that-gets-the-connection-string-from-user-secrets

Answer (score 0):

This is issue [#8163](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/8163). You can safely ignore the error. It will be fixed in 2.0.0-preview2-final.

Comment: Thanks. No workaround in the current latest stable version? I am using just a simple class library to create this migration.

Comment: It's typically caused by logging messages containing a colon early in your `Startup` class. You can try and suppress those messages if you can find them.

Comment: It's now Feb 2018, I'm using VS2017 with EF 2.0.1, and this bug/issue is still alive and kicking.  When is this stuff actually going to work properly out of the box ?!!  I'm trying to follow an 8-month-old Microsoft tutorial, and almost every other step throws a problem, which I have to go off Googling for...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model