# ef-core Add-Migration not working

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

just started learning dot net core 2.0.

when i try to create migration:

```
PM> Add-Migration InitialModel
```

i get error:

> Add-Migration : Exception calling "Substring" with "1" argument(s):
>   "StartIndex cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: startIndex" At
>   line:1 char:1
>   + Add-Migration InitialModel
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Migration], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException,Add-Migration

my dotnet --info

> .NET Command Line Tools (2.0.0)
>
> Product Information:  Version:            2.0.0  Commit SHA-1 hash: 
>   cdcd1928c9
>
> Runtime Environment:  OS Name:     Windows  OS Version:  10.0.15063 
>   OS Platform: Windows  RID:         win10-x64  Base Path:   C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\
>
> Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host
>
> Version  : 2.0.0   Build    :
>   e8b8861ac7faf042c87a5c2f9f2d04c98b69f28d

my csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

thanks for help!

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44178411/error-in-migrations-in-efcore)?

Comment: Hmm... That issue should be fixed in 2.0.0. @user3373603 Can you [submit a new issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/new)?

Comment: @bricelam ok, i will create issue, as workaround i add migration with developer command prompt `dotnet ef migrations add`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen this error occur if the v1.x version of the PMC (Package Manager Console) migration commands are loaded in Visual Studio and then you try to run the commands against a v2.x application. E.g. if you create or open an ASP.NET Core 1.1 application and then you create an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application in the same Visual Studio session.

The workaround for this case is to re-start Visual Studio before you work with the 2.0 application.

According to [bricelam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/475031/bricelam) there is a mechanism in NuGet that should cause the load of the newer version of the PMC commands into Visual Studio but unfortunately the mechanism is not triggered in all cases.